# error in function when creating struct

Tags: c, function

im new to c and having few issues with the struc and functions calls. I have created a struct and I have few functions. but in one of the functions i am getting an error. it says "no matching function for call to". im getting this error in the line which returns the drawCurves_V function. could anyone kindly let me know where I am going wrong

my code is

```
typedef struct
{
    struct
    {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
    }inside [4];

}point;


point Plot(float u, float v){

   point temp[4];

   for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
       temp[i] = drawCurves_U(u,i);

   return drawCurves_V(v, temp);
}
```

Comment: The error says it doesn't find `drawCurves_V` and you don't show us `drawCurves_V`. Does this function exists ?

Comment: You should provide your implementation for the drawCurves functions too  - can you edit the question to provide this?

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is very clear and it is telling you exactly what is missing.

You are returning the `drawCurves_V()` and there is no matching function to it.

```
return drawCurves_V(v, temp);
```

You need to provide an implementation for the function `drawCurves_V()`

Comment: I have mentioned that function in my program. just wanted to keep the code small while asking the question.

Comment: @user3350521:- In that case you have to show the code of your function as it is difficult to predict what is the error without watching the code of your function!